# Get full page HTML for a non-public Wordpress page

Tags: api, http, http-api, curl

How can I write a function that will return the full rendered HTML of a non-public URL on my Wordpress site—a URL that you must be logged in to see, such as a draft? Not just the post content, but the full rendered HTML that a browser would receive, from `<!doctype` to `</html>`?

I would normally accomplish something like this with cURL, but in this case, a plain cURL would result in a 404—because the desired page is only accessible if you are a logged-in Wordpress user. I have seen examples of [WordPress authentication with cURL](http://w4dev.com/wp/login-using-curl/), but they all seem to require you to hard-code a username and password, which I would like to avoid because a) it seems insecure, and b) Wordpress users can change their password at any time.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
function getFullPageHtml( $url ) { // pass in a url (post ID would be fine too)

   // Do something here that does not involve hard-coding a WP username password

   return $html; // a string of the full page's HTML--'<!doctype...etc...</html>'
}
```

Is there a different approach that would get me this result without relying on including  username and password in the code? For example, using output buffers instead of making a cURL/HTTP request?

Comment: It is possible to use cache plugin, there create a static page. You can use the result. Also it is possible to export via plugin the content of each post, but without the theme, the front end. Is it this, what you mean?

Comment: You really need to rework that question. It's extremely unclear what you're asking

Comment: @kaiser I've rewritten it, attempting to make it more straightforward. How's this version?

Comment: The revision is much better (in my opinion) but under what conditions do you want someone to be allowed to see the page? And why does the ordinary "preview" functionality not work for you?

Comment: It's better as I now understand that you want to have an URL that returns `404` for non logged in visitors, right? What I don't get, is what this has to do with WP HTTP API and auth protocols used for connecting to 3rd party sites and services.

Comment: @kaiser Right, I removed all references to APIs and WP HTTP API for that reason. It's not essential to the question. Is there a way to get this re-opened?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I don't need to preview or make the page viewable per se, I just need to be able to run the function that returns the HTML. (The end game is to post the resulting HTML string to an external API, a point which I removed from the question.)

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. I can't answer here, but see [here](https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/8596870) explaination are on comments.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks, that's fantastic. I need to get this question reopened so that you can post this as an answer. To any readers who can vote to reopen, you can check the revision history to see that the question was completely rewritten to clarify. I think the question is now quite clear enough to be of value to the community.